# Is it possible to modify Adobe Air's WebKit settings in the mx:HTML component?

Tags: webkit, air

Adobe Air's (read: Flex) mx:HTML component uses WebKit to render webpages. As such, does anyone know of a way to tweak WebKit's settings via the Air application (or a Flex API)?  For example, I'd like to set WebKit's "enable-private-browsing" setting from "false" to "true".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible, I've logged a ticket here: bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25585  Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

That would be very interesting.
Sadly, judging by the source code of the HTML component and the AIR documentation, it doesn't seem that there's any way to do so.

Maybe something to propose to the Flex/AIR team on [JIRA](http://bugs.adobe.com/flex) for the next version.

Comment: I've logged a ticket here: http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-25585  Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

For standalone application (e.g. stand for exhibition) you can build your own WebKit.